# PHP/MySql Connection Overhead

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have recently completed a data layer for a PHP application. In my data layer I have various methods for executing different sql tasks such as selects, inserts, deletes, etc. Coming from a .NET background, I practice opening connections, doing whatever with the connection, and closing them.

In a recent code review, I was questioned about this practice, and a colleague stated it was best to leave connections open for the life of the application. Their reasoning is that opening/closing connections is time consuming. My argument is that leaving them open is resource consuming. Following is a code sample from the data layer that executes a select query. I am fairly new to PHP so I don't really have a response for the critique. Can anyone provide any insight into this?

```
    public static final function executeSelectQuery($qry){
        $connection = mysql_connect(ADS_DB_HOST, ADS_DB_USERNAME, ADS_DB_PASSWORD) or die(ADS_ERROR_MSG . mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db(ADS_DB_NAME) or die(ADS_ERROR_MSG . mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query($qry) or die(ADS_ERROR_MSG . mysql_error());
        mysql_close();

        $results = array();
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(($result))){
            $results[] = $rows;
        }
        return sprintf('{"results":{"rows":%s}}', json_encode($results));
    }
```

Comment: *Benchmark it* both ways. But yes, reestablishing a connection is typically much more expensive than leaving a connection open a few milliseconds longer.

Comment: Actually I should have been more clear. This data layer will be used for web services that provide data for mobile devices. The data layer is not for use in a web application. Not sure if this makes a difference

Comment: Don't these devices use HTTP?

Comment: If you create new code, you should use PDO or mysqli rather than the deprecated mysql interface - http://www.php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic case of the speed vs memory usage trade-off. There is no one-answer-fits-all to this question; it comes down to which of the two is the most important for the particular project you are undertaking.

Edit: After reading the new comments I see this project is aimed at mobile devices. In this case I would say that due to the limited memory of mobile devices (as opposed to the boatload available to most desktops nowadays) prioritising memory usage would be the right call since everyone expects mobile devices to be rather slow in comparison to desktops anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague is right and this code is wrong.
Ask your self a question, what certain resources does consume an opened connection.

To add to the code review, your idea of error handling is wrong. Never use die to handle an error but throw an Exception instead.

Also, do not craft JSON manually.

```
return json_encode(array("results" => array ("rows" => $results)));
```

Also, consider to amend this unction to make it accept values for the parameterized query

Comment: This cannot be answered in a general way. You simply do not know it. It is a descriptor for the socket, but could be lots of memory at the server-side to maintain client state/information.

Comment: Quite contrary, for PHP it's quite possible.

Comment: Thanks, even though this doesn't address the original question, it's good info. As I said in my original question, I'm new to PHP.